# Refactor code by reducing multiple "OR" condition

Tags: c#, refactoring

```
if (policyNumber.StartsWith("CM"))
  return "POLICIES";
else if (policyNumber.StartsWith("W002"))
  return "ANNUITY";
else if (policyNumber.StartsWith("W007"))
  return "VARIABLE ANNUITY";
else if (policyNumber.StartsWith("H0032") || 
         ((policyNumber.StartsWith("1") || 
           policyNumber.StartsWith("2") || 
           policyNumber.StartsWith("3") || 
         policyNumber.StartsWith("4")) && policyNumber.Length == 10))
  return "INT POLICIES";
else if (policyNumber.StartsWith("W003") || 
         policyNumber.StartsWith("W004") || 
         policyNumber.StartsWith("W008") || 
        (policyNumber.StartsWith("0000") && policyNumber.Length == 11))
  return "WS POLICIES";
```

For the above code, the sonar cube throws critical code smells. Is there any alternative way to reduce the multiple "||" conditions?

Comment: "critical code smells" here usually means the if statement should end with an else branch.

Comment: Seeing as you `return` for every `if`/`else if` case, you can replace each `else if` with `if`. Then, after the very last `if (...) return ...;`, you may want to add a simple `return string.Empty;` (or some other appropriate value for when none of the `if` conditions matched).

Comment: Maybe you can also optimize a little with the order. You have conditions on first char, only, first 2 and first 4 where index 0..2 overlap ... do you have estimates on which will appear most often? And if so would it be significant enough to be considered?

Comment: Didn't Benchmark, but just as an outlandish alternative: https://dotnetfiddle.net/g1WA5c

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see there are 3 different scenarios:

- Direct mapping:

  - *if it starts with *XYZ* then return *BlahBlahBlah**
- Length constraint and single pattern:

  - *if its length is *L* and it starts with *XYZ* then return *BlahBlahBlah**
- Length constraint and multi patterns

  - *if its length is *L* and it starts with any of the *XYZ* s then return *BlahBlahBlah**

### Direct mappings

```
Dictionary<string, string> directMappings = new()
{
    {"CM",    "POLICIES"},
    {"W002",  "ANNUITY"},
    {"W007",  "VARIABLE ANNUITY"},
    {"H0032", "INT POLICIES"},
    {"W003",  "WS POLICIES"},
    {"W004",  "WS POLICIES"},
    {"W008",  "WS POLICIES"},
};

...
foreach(var(pattern, value) in directMappings) 
{
    if(policyNumber.StartsWith(pattern))
        return value;
}
```

### Length constraint and single pattern

```
if (policyNumber.Length == 11 && policyNumber.StartsWith("0000"))
    return "WS POLICIES";
```

### Length constraint and multi patterns

```
string[] tenLongPolicyNumberPrefixes = new[] {"1", "2", "3", "4"}; 

...
if (policyNumber.Length == 10 && tenLongPolicyNumberPrefixes.Any(policyNumber.StartsWith)) 
    return "INT POLICIES";
```

---

You can make the collections class-level `static` to avoid on-demand allocations.

Answer (score 0):

I would do such a rewrite:

```
   public static string Policy(string policyNumber)
   {
       Func <string, string[], bool> containsList = (string p, string[] lst) => lst.Any(s => p.StartsWith(s));

       return policyNumber switch
       {
           var p when p.StartsWith("CM") => "POLICIES",
           var p when p.StartsWith("W002") => "ANNUITY",
           var p when p.StartsWith("W007") => "VARIABLE ANNUITY",
           var p when p.StartsWith("H0032") || (p.Length == 10 && containsList(p, new[] {"1","2","3","4"})) => "INT POLICIES",
           var p when containsList(p, new[] { "W003", "W004", "W008"}) || (p.Length == 11 && p.StartsWith("0000")) => "WS POLICIES",
           _ => throw new ArgumentException("Invalid policy code")
       };
   }
```